# WSO2 METRIC DB corrupted

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

For my qa instance of WSO2 API Manager (2.0.0), I am facing issues with the log files increasing rapidly. I tried to manage the log file sizes through config settings (Carbon and Audit). However, I find the other logs files are filling fast - especially the http_access*.log and wso2-apigw-errors.log. Right now I have written a shell script to remove them periodically. The real problem behind these growing logs files has to do with the corrupted METRIC H2 DB, I think.

```
TID: [] [] [2017-11-11 08:45:37,589] ERROR 
{org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter} -  Error when 
reporting gauges {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter}
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Sequence 
"SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_1AC7F1C3_AD26_4518_BBF0_1E63028E0201" not found; SQL statement:
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.METRIC_TIMER(
    ID BIGINT DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_1AC7F1C3_AD26_4518_BBF0_1E63028E0201) NOT NULL NULL_TO_DEFAULT SEQUENCE PUBLIC.SYSTEM_SEQUENCE_1AC7F1C3_AD26_4518_BBF0_1E63028E0201,
SOURCE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
TIMESTAMP BIGINT NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
COUNT BIGINT NOT NULL,
MAX DOUBLE NOT NULL,
MEAN DOUBLE NOT NULL,
MIN DOUBLE NOT NULL,
STDDEV DOUBLE NOT NULL,
P50 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
P75 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
P95 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
P98 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
P99 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
P999 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
MEAN_RATE DOUBLE NOT NULL,
M1_RATE DOUBLE NOT NULL,
M5_RATE DOUBLE NOT NULL,
M15_RATE DOUBLE NOT NULL,
RATE_UNIT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DURATION_UNIT VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) [90036-140]
```

For now, I have disabled the Metrics (metrics.xml). How can I reset the Metrics H2 DB and start collecting metrics again? Or how can I point the Metrics DB to an RDBMS?

Answer (score 1):

1) To get the H2 working:

- Shut down the server.
- Delete `WSO2METRICS_DB.h2.db and WSO2METRICS_DB.lock.db` files in
  `<APIM_HOME>/repository/database/`.
- Start the server again with `./wso2server.sh -Dsetup`

2) Update `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/datasources/metrics-datasources.xml` with your RDBMS database details and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this.